# MYSQL Case When simply not working

Tags: mysql, sql, case, case-when

I'm trying to convert my TIMESTAMP to a string that represents the financial year period e.g. April to March

Here is my following statement:

```
SELECT Year, Type
CASE 
WHEN date_format(SubmissionDate, '%Y')='2015' AND MONTH(SubmissionDate)
BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN '15-16'
WHEN date_format(SubmissionDate, '%Y')='2016' AND MONTH(SubmissionDate)
BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '15-16'
END as Year
FROM Incidents
```

Obviously it fails...I pretty knew when it comes to CASE statements, am I anywhere near?

Comment: where's comma after `Type`?

Comment: Your absolutely right!, many thanks to you both for pointing this out!..I will check more carefully next time!

Comment: Please mark the answer as **ACCEPTED** so that others will find the issue  **resolved**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a `,` after `Type`:

```
SELECT Year, Type,
CASE 
WHEN date_format(SubmissionDate, '%Y')='2015' AND MONTH(SubmissionDate)
BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN '15-16'
WHEN date_format(SubmissionDate, '%Y')='2016' AND MONTH(SubmissionDate)
BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '15-16'
END as Year
FROM Incidents
```

Comment: Apologies! well thats a tad embarrassing! many thanks for your help!...works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you would mix functions like this.  Why not do:

```
SELECT Year, Type,
       (CASE WHEN YEAR(SubmissionDate) = 2015  AND MONTH(SubmissionDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 12
             THEN '15-16'
             WHEN YEAR(SubmissionDate) = 2016 AND MONTH(SubmissionDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
             THEN '15-16'
        END) as Year
FROM Incidents;
```

Or, even more simply:

```
SELECT Year, Type,
       (CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE_SUB(SubmissionDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) = 2015  
             THEN '15-16'
        END) as Year
FROM Incidents;
```